# Race condition in Django save()

Tags: django, database, django-models, concurrency, race-condition

I have an API that can take a list of files and save it in the DB for a specific user. I want to limit the number of files per user to be some number. The way I enforce this is through overriding the save method:
A pseudocode:
In the view:

```
For item in list_to_save:
    item.save()
```

And save method:

```
curr_count= Files.objects.filter(id=user_id).count
If curr_count > max_count:
    Get curr_count-max_count item
    For del in delete:
       del.delete()
```

Question is, will this lead to a race condition if the same user tries to send 2 different list of files?
Since there might be 2 save operation running at the same time?

I am expecting that there is some race condition since the two server will see that DB has entries, and will try to delete them both, leading to some inconsitencies